# Confused about printout of function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple code in python and it's working fine but I am confused that it's not printing properly.
first print statement works but not the second print statement. Kindly help me with this issue.
Here is the code:

```
def isRepeat(inputString):
    flag = False
    print(inputString)# printing this perfectly
    if len(inputString) % 2 !=0:
        return False 
    else:
        for i in range(len(inputString)//2):  
            print("x")
            if inputString.count(inputString[i]) %2  == 0:
                 flag = True
            else: 
                return False
    return flag

output:

    inputString = "2w2ww"
    isRepeat(inputString)

    2w2ww
    False
```

Comment: So it's not working fine?

Comment: the length of your input string is 5 so you're returning false on line 5

Comment: Editing is for adding details to your question, not changing the question itself. Please ask a new question if you need assistance with something else. By the way, book recommandations are off topic on SO

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The second print statement `print('x')` doens't run in your example because that test is hitting the first `return False`, in order to see that second print you need to test with a string that has an even length, example: `inputString = "2w2www"`